# log4j2 converstion to Ecslayout and masking

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, log4j2

Currently log masking for sensitive fields is working fine using log4j2, now I want to change the log format to ecs.
so I made the changes in log4j2.xml and EcsLayout tag as below:

```
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" status="OFF"
           packages="com.usbank.digitalservices.common.log.mask">
<Properties>
    <Property name="base.log.dir">./logs</Property>
    <Property name="appenderPatternLayout">%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'} %-5p %-15c{1} [%X]: %spi%n</Property>
    <Property name="maxLogFileSize">10 MB</Property>
    <Property name="maxLogFiles">2</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
<Console name="CONSOLELOG" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
      <!--  <PatternLayout pattern="${appenderPatternLayout}"/> -->
        **<EcsLayout stackTraceAsArray="true"  serviceName="my-api"/>** 
 </Console>
```

Now log is converted to json correctly but the masking is not working i mean appenderPatternLayout /spi not working.

any suggestion for how to mask if EcsLayout, what could be parameters for appenderPatternLayout?

Answer (score 0):

The `%spi` pattern you are using is clearly provided by a private Log4j2 plugin from `com.usbank.digitalservices.common.log.mask`.

The `EcsLayout` can not take advantage of pattern converters, but the generic [JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) can. You just need to copy the [embedded `EcsLayout.json` template](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-layout-template-json/src/main/resources/EcsLayout.json) and replace the definition of "message" with:

```json
"message": {
  "$resolver": "pattern",
  "pattern": "%spi",
  "stackTraceEnabled": false
}
```